How does quantum computing pseudocode look like?
In classical programming, pseudocode follows some informal but widely understood standards, focusing on clarity and abstraction while omitting low-level implementation details. However, quantum computing introduces a fundamentally different paradigm, which seems to lack a universally agreed-upon pseudocode style.
In classical computing, the paradigm revolves around providing input and an algorithm (model) to produce an output. In contrast, quantum computing flips this paradigm.
Quantum computing takes the output and model (algorithm) as given and produces the input probabilistically.
This is still different from the machine learning paradigm, where the input and output are known, and the model is returned.
Quantum algorithms like Grover’s search or Shor’s factorization rely on superposition, interference, and probability, which makes their pseudocode different from traditional programming.
For example, quantum data types extend classical types:

Booleans:
For Classical, True or False.
For Quantum, True, False, or Superposition, representing an uncertain state that is only resolved (measured) probabilistically.

Integers:
Superpositions of integers must represent a power-of-2 range. For example, an unsigned integer in superposition with an 8-bit type could range from 0 to 31 (nearest power of 2), even though 8-bit can be a wider range like from 0 to 255.


Problem Example: Factorization of 24
Here’s my hypothetical pseudocode for finding the factors of  using Grover’s algorithm:
// Pseudocode for quantum factorization of 24 using Grover's Algorithm

// Step 1: Initialize Quantum State
// Represent a and b as integers in superposition, initialized to [0, 31]
// (the closest power of 2 range for unsigned integers)
Declare a, b as UnsignedInteger8 in Superposition
Set a, b range: [1, 24] (limit range in interpretation)

// Step 2: Define Oracle
// Oracle identifies valid (a, b) pairs where a * b = 24
Define Oracle O(a, b):
  if a * b == 24:
    Mark (a, b) as a solution (flip amplitude sign)

// Step 3: Define Diffusion Operator
Define DiffusionOperator(state):
  Reflect state about the average amplitude

// Step 4: Grover Iterations
Repeat Grover iterations k times (k ~ sqrt(N)):
  Apply Oracle O
  Apply DiffusionOperator

// Step 5: Measure Quantum State
Measure state of a, b to collapse them into specific values

// Step 6: Interpret Result
Return measured (a, b) pair as potential solution
  Probability distribution gives higher weight to correct factors (a, b)

The state of $a$ and $b$ starts as a superposition of all possible unsigned integer pairs. Even though the data type is defined as UnsignedInteger8, the practical range for the factorization is limited to $[1,24]$. Superposition requires power-of-2 ranges, so we conceptually work with $[0,31]$ a.k.a 5-qubits and ignore irrelevant states, the rest 3-qubits.
The oracle identifies pairs where $a×b=24$, and Grover’s search amplifies their probability. Upon measurement, the superposition collapses into specific values for and $a$ and $b$ giving a high likelihood of correct factors (e.g., $6×4=24$).
So, how should quantum computing pseudocode be written to abstract away the low-level details of quantum physics and computer engineering (like qubit registers, gates, etc.), and instead focus on native data types (e.g., integers, strings) and the high-level logic of the algorithm?
Are there such conventions or standards for writing such pseudocode? How would you generalize the pseudocode for quantum problems like this factorization example, where the abstraction level is closer to that of classical programming?
I feel, using amplitude term, is still related with low-level detail of quantum physics, as the classical paradigm usually care the definite answer, not probabilistic.

"Quantum computing takes the input and model (algorithm) as given and produces the output probabilistically".
Are you sure? I doubt this interpretation of QC. The input-output behaviour of QC is similar to randomized computation.  Although there are some subtly to this comparison. But I don't think there is such flip a of input-output as you have mentioned.

@108_mk No, I said. Quantum computing takes the output and model (algorithm) as given and produces the input probabilistically. The factorization problem from multiplication result can be considered as finding the two multiplicands (inputs) of the multiplication result (output). While the multiplier itself (e.g. HRSCumulativeMultiplier as Oracle) can be considered as part of the algorithm. That problem easily solved by quantum computer due to symetrical nature, but hard for classical computer due to asymetrical nature (one-way logic gates).
